# Saving config file safely on the disk - Windows

Tags: c#, c++, windows, desktop-application

I am having one situation related to security and need your valuable suggestions or solutions.
So the story goes like this:
There is a Windows (consider Win 7 and above. This is an end user machine and not any server) machine and it is having 2 desktop applications. One is written in C++ and the other is written in C#.
One application emits some data as configurations which I need to save on this machine (on disk), later when another application wakes up, it will pick the configuration file and do whatever it is supposed to do.
Both the applications are 2 different application. There is no relationship between them except that they are installed on the same machine.
Now, from the security and consistency point of view, I do not want that user access this file and play with this/update it or delete it.

So my question here is what is the best way (or safest place) to secure the file on the Windows machine so that user will not be able to temper it? The amount of config data is very small - consider 3 string fields like first name, last name and age in json format.

Thanks.

Comment: You can't. If your application can access the location, the user can, unless you're running in a different security context. If you need the file to be unreadable by the user, encrypt it.

Comment: As an addition to encrypting it you can hide it through obscurity, give it a senseless name and a senseless extension and bury it somewhere between your other application files. Mark it as a hidden file. You name it. Why are you afraid users will modify it?

Comment: You could serialize it in binary format since encryption sounds like overkill for what you're trying to achieve... something like http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeToBson.htm

Comment: The machine belongs to the user.  They're *entitled* to modify the file if they want to.  (Of course, if that breaks something, it's their fault, not yours.  Provided you put the file in a sensible location, that is.)